# Converting ePDF to a non searchable pdf programmatically

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox

I need to OCR a readable pdf again to generate hOCR file.
I am using,

> Apache PDFBox -> parse the readable pdf
> Qoppa -> OCR the pdf

Currently, I am trying iText to create a pdf after converting PDF page to image using PDFRenderer from PDfbox.

```
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("iTextImageExample.pdf"));
    document.open();
    Image img = Image.getInstance("C:\\Projects\\Data Mapping\\singularity-data-jockey-pdflib\\src\\test\\resources\\data\\pageimg.jpg");
    document.add(img);
```

I also tried with Qoppa PDfDocument class.
The issue is, the output pdf generated from the image is low quality and OCR is not accurate. Is there any other way to convert the pdf to non searchable pdf?

Comment: "the output pdf generated from the image is low quality" -> check the images first. In PDFBox you can decide the resolution.

Comment: Hi @TilmanHausherr I have a requirement for the scaling factor of the image to be 1 (72dpi) if I generate an image with 72dpi the generated image is low quality

Comment: 72 dpi won't look good. You can generate at a higher dpi and scale appropriately when creating the new PDF.